# Calculating Principal curves

Tags: differential-geometry

I have been given a surface patch, $X(u,v)$, and I have calculated its unit normal, coefficiants of its first and second fundamental form and found its principal curvatures. Now it's asking me to find the principal "curves" and she they equal what they have given me. How do I find these curves? Is it just the eigenvectors of the matrix used to find the principal curvature multipled by $X_u$ and $X_v$?

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you know the eigenvectors of that matrix (shape operator), you have two vector fields on the surface. These are called principal directions (not well defined at umbilic points!). For each eigenvalue you have an ODE to solve, that gives you two families of curves on the surface which are called "principal curves".

See Wikipedia, [Line of Curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_curvature#Line_of_curvature). Be careful, though. as I explain in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/364267/2002).